# SlickEdit 17---Why auto copy

Tags: copy, selection, clipboard, slickedit

I'm now puzzled by the behavior of SE about the auto-copy feature.

**First**,when I double click on any word,the word will be copied to the clipboard,however I never found any other editor which behaves like this.This is actually annoying exspecially when you want to paste one word to another word by double click the other word to select it.

**Second**,When I select a block by moving the mouse ,the selection area is automatically copied to the clipboard,which makes me quite depressed because I select the block just to highlight it but not to copy it.

As you see,these two features both concern about the clipboard in SE.I actually don't think they are good designs.Or is there any way to close these features,I will be very grateful to get any helpfull advice here.Here is my e-mail[***[hustwsh2011@gmail.com][1]***] if you would be so nice to send the answer to my mailbox.It's also welcomed to post your answer here so as to help others who are also puzzling by this problem.

Comment: No one (besides maybe slick edit support) going to email you ... not here

Comment: You need to provide more info: (1) What emulation mode are you in, (2) WHat does it list in "Options->Keyboard and Mouse->Key Bindings", when you select the mouse icon (select R or L DoubleCLick), (3) is this different than any other version of slick edit that you used

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
_command paste_replace_whole_word_fixed(){
  // I assign this to A-DEL INS
  delete_full_word();
  paste();
}
```